# How to run a CellularAutomaton until a configuration is repeated?

Tags: cellular-automata

I would like to do something like `CellularAutomaton[10, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 2^5]`, but instead of running for `2^5` steps, it should stop as soon as a configuration has been seen twice, and report the number of such steps taken. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the one-step functional version with `NestWhileList`:

```
NestWhileList[CellularAutomaton[30, #] &, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, UnsameQ, All]
```

> {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 
>     0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1}}

For the number of steps taken until a configuration repeats:

```
Length @ %
```

> 7

**Note:** In general, `CellularAutomaton[rule, init, n]` can  also be obtained by nesting the one-step functional version using `NestList[CellularAutomaton[rule, #]&, init, n]`:

```
CellularAutomaton[30, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 2^5] == 
  NestList[CellularAutomaton[30, #] &, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 2^5]
```

> True

Comment: One could use `UnsameQ` instead of `DuplicateFreeQ @ {##} &` in the third argument.

Comment: @J.M. Right; much better. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[f]

f[state_] := f[f[state] = CellularAutomaton[30, state]]

{f[{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}], Length@DownValues[f]}
```

> `{{0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 7}`

Comment: Interesting solution! This looks a bit like [Floyd's algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd%27s_Tortoise_and_Hare).